# Export image with canvas

Tags: jquery, image, canvas

I'm creating an application (based only on HTML, CSS and jQuery) where I will create an image based on layers (just a bunch of divs one above each other) and then I will need to export it, so the user can download the final version as JPG or PNG.

There's any way to export the **canvas content** as a downloadable image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
canvas.toDataURL()
```

also see:

```
canvas.toBlob()
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, you cannot make the browser download a file it's generated itself.

However, you can use the canvas element's `Canvas.getDataURL()` method. It returns the image data, as a base64 encoded PNG. You could upload this to your server with Ajax, have the server convert it to a normal PNG file again (or even another file type), and then have the client download the image from the server.

I know it's a litte strange way around the problem, but should be easily done.

Comment: canvas.toDataURL() simply does the job.